# uploading MS Access databases to the web

Tags: database

I found an easy system for uploading searchable MS Access databases to the web - it's called Caspio Online (http://www.caspio.com/). However, I would rather not pay a monthly fee just to upload databases to our website. Does anyone know of an open source alternative that will allow me to upload a MS Access 2007 Database to a website, and then build a web form that will search it?

The easier the implementation, the better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand, no. But you might be best advised to go with an open source database and some search web code.

Migrating from [Access to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html) is easy, and writing a php web form that can perform your custom search is pretty simple too. If you want a sql query window, then you can install webmin or [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) which has a nice '[query by example](http://www.packtpub.com/article/multi-table-query-generator-using-phpmyadmin-mysql)' feature.